# Infinite Loop; Condition is met

Tags: javascript, for-loop, infinite-loop

I'm having an issue with a for loop that won't end even though one of its conditions is met. The condition in question is the `dir + i * move < 0`. I can start the loop at 0 and it will begin to decrement itself, immediately starting at -1 on the first iteration. Why wouldn't it immediately stop?

I put a safety inside the loop (`if (dir + i * move < 0) { break; }`) to break it if that same condition is met and it works, but I didn't think I would have to do that. Even if the loop has to cycle once before it checks its conditions shouldn't it stop looping at that point?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here's the JS:

```
function focusNearest(cell, xDist, yDist) {

let answers = Object.keys(newPuzzle.answerKey);
let orderedRows = activeRows.sort(function(a, b) { return a - b; })
let orderedCols = activeCols.sort();

let id = cell.id;
let split = id.match(/[\d\.]+|\D+/g);
let col = split[0];
let row = parseInt(split[1]);
let x = orderedRows.indexOf(row);
let y = orderedCols.indexOf(col);

let across = Math.abs(xDist) > Math.abs(yDist);
let axis = across ? orderedCols : orderedRows;
let dir = across ? y : x;
let move = across ? xDist : yDist;

let destX;
let destY;
let destRow;
let destCol;

let destination;

let currPos = activeGroup.indexOf(id);

for (let i = 1; dir + i * move < axis.length || dir + i * move < 0; i++) {

    // TEST
    if (dir + i * move < 0) { break; } // TODO: REMOVE

    let jumpX = xDist * i;
    let jumpY = yDist * i;

    destX = x + jumpY;
    destY = y + jumpX;
    destRow = activeRows[destX];
    destCol = activeCols[destY];
    candidate = destCol + destRow;

    if (answers.includes(candidate)) {
        destination = candidate;
        break;
    }

}

focusCell(destination, selectDir(destination)[0]);
```

}

Comment: the loop counter starts at its initialized value `for ( i=1; ...)`. The OR clause returns FALSE when both conditions are FALSE (otherwise TRUE) - this may be the infinite loop.  If you mean to test for "out of range" then maybe you want `... > axis.length`

Comment: So, it doesn't test if *either* condition is true? How would I do that? I need it to quit if it's less than 0.

Comment: 1) output all the variables & calculations for each loop.   2)  "... it doesn't test..."  Not sure what that means. Conditionals return true or false - there is no "does not test".  for loops continue when the condition is TRUE.  3)  I suspect that all the math calc. variables  are positive so the math will always be greater than or equal to zero;  Then I'm GUESSING `axis.length` value is less than the math ->  thus false || false is TRUE, hence never ending loop,